# How to get a Dictionary Object from a Web Service

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I'm using a web service that gives back JSON data of jobs. I have called the service and displayed ALL the JSON data as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *urlString = @"http://jobs.github.com/positions.json?description=python&location=new+york";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSString *item = [json objectAtIndex:0];



NSLog(@"%@", item);



// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
```

}

So this returns one job with  TON of information such as "description", "company name", "location". I want to be able to get JUST location or JUST description. How would I go about doing that?

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Parse the JSON into its corresponding NSDictionary and/or NSArray objects using NSJSONSerialization and then access the dictionaries/arrays as necessary.

Comment: (What you apparently get back from that site is an array of objects (dictionaries), one object for each position.  Fairly simple to iterate through the array and extract the info you want.)

Comment: For some reason my web service is weird...I get two objects per link and duplicate dictionary objects...

Comment: If you NSLog `json` you will see an array (bracketed by `()`) containing multiple dictionaries (bracketed by `{}`).  I figure there are 8-10 different job descriptions, and each will be a separate dictionary in the translated JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can access it directly:

```
NSDictionary *item = [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *location = [item objectForKey:@"location"];
NSLog(@"%@", location);
```

Comment: This answer was perfect. It was precise and EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: Remember, there's 8-10 different job descriptions there.  The above only fetches info for one of them.

Comment: Hot Licks is right. Just tested it and found out Armands solution is better if you need all locations :)

Answer (score 2):

you get an array of dictionaries... replace

```
NSString *item = [json objectAtIndex:0];  //old
```

with

```
for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Item desc : %@", item[@"description"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the following article will give you a good grounding on parsing JSON data.

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/basic-json-parsing-in-ios/